# First Value Function to return null in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to fetch first result.

I'm using the below query for performing the operation

```
select id,firstname,dob,assignment
from (
     select table1.id as id, 
            table1.name as firstname,
            table1.dob as dob,
            First_value(table2.Res)over (partition by table2.id order by table2.date asc) f,
            table2.Res as assignment
     from table1,table2
     where  table1.id  = table2.id and
) where assignment = f
```

Lets assume there are no records in table2. In that case my expected output should be

```
id   firstname   dob          assignment
 1   Ana         23/03/1960   null
```

The query works fine if there is a record in table2. But the above query is not returning any results if there are no records for a particular employee in table2.

Comment: `...table1.id  = table2.id and )` is a *syntax error*

Comment: from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.id is an INNER JOIN, so if table2 is empty the result is zero rows. Try with LEFT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT id,firstname,dob,assignment
FROM (
       SELECT table1.id as id, 
              table1.name as firstname,
              table1.dob as dob,
              First_value(table2.Res)over(partition by table2.id order by table2.date asc) f,
              table2.Res as assignment
       FROM table1
       LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id  = table2.id 
 ) WHERE ( assignment = f OR ( assignment IS NULL AND f IS NULL) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Of course your query returns no rows if one of the tables is empty.  That is how a cross joins and inner joins work.

Presumably you want a `left join` and a simpler query:

```
select t1.id as id, t1.name as firstname,t1.dob as dob,
       First_value(t2.Res)over (partition by t2.id order by t2.date asc) f,
       t2.Res as assignment
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id  = t2.id and t2.Res = 'f';
```

Comment: `where t2.Res = 'f'` is a problem since all fields in `t2` will be null if there is no row in `t2`.

Comment: I tried using left join as well. Still it doesn't return any result when there are no entries in 2nd table